# JQuery hide/show playlist on hover

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a project where I have a player and a playlist. Now I want to show/hide the playlist on hovering on the player itself. I've come so far that I can hide/show the playlist on hovering over a link. I've also put delay on the fade out of the playlist, but the problem is that I want the command to stop if the cursor is on the playlist itself. When you then move the mouse out, it should go away. See what happens now http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/player/annar.htm.

This is the script I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".jp-playlist").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').hover(function(){
        jQuery('.jp-playlist').delay(200).fadeIn();
        }, function() {
        jQuery('.jp-playlist').delay(1000).fadeOut();  
    });

});
```

This is the link to the a test page:
http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/player/annar.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want, the link opens and closes the playlist, and moving the mouse out of the box closes it.

please try:

http://jsfiddle.net/YupEe/5/

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
$('#jp_player_1').hover({...});
```

not work?

Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, use

```
$('#jp_player_1').on({
    mouseenter: function(){...},
    mouseleave: function(){...}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the setTimeout function.

```
var fadeOutFunction;
var fadeInFunction;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".jp-playlist").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(fadeOutFunction);
        fadeInFunction = setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.jp-playlist').fadeIn(); },200);
        }, function() {
        clearTimeout(fadeInFunction);
        fadeInFunction = setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.jp-playlist').fadeOut();}, 1000);  
    });

});
```

and, if you want the command to stop if the cursor is on the playlist itself, just add clearTimeout for playlist onhover event.